# Can you become an astronaut with Strabismus?

Tags: career, qualification-testing, astronaut-recruitment

When I was 2 years old, I had eye surgery and got diagnosed with strabismus. Strabismus is an eye condition where both eyes don’t look at exactly the same spot. Would I still be able to become an astronaut?

Comment: What kind of astronaut do you want to be? These days all you have to do is pay some (okay, a lot of) money and you can get a ride into space.

Comment: I want to be a normal astronaut, like Buzz Aldrin or Neal Armstrong.

Answer (score 4):

Best bet is to contact NASA and ask them. Here is some info I got from NASA astronaut hiring procedures concerning PHYSICAL requirements:
Your height has to be between 62 to 75 inches (between 1,58m to 1,90m)
There are no indications specified by NASA about the weight you must reach, but you must be in good physical shape according to your age and your gender.
Certain things will disqualify you immediately, for example kidney stones, even if you’ve only had one once.

Visual acuity is probably the requirement that generates the most questions for astronaut candidates. Distant and near visual acuity must be CORRECTABLE to 20/20 for each eye. The use of glasses is acceptable. Corrective eye surgery operations, PKR and Lasik, are permitted. If your vision is no worse than 20/400 and correctable to 20/20 you can be considered. If your vision is no worse than 20/800 and LASIK can put you into the “20/400 correctable to 20/20” category then you are also good go. To qualify, 2 years must have passed between the surgery and your application to become an astronaut. Also, blood pressure must not exceed 140/90 measured in sitting position.
For more info, go to :
https://www.nasa.gov/stem-ed-resources/how-to-be-an-astronaut.html
also read this article :
https://www.fromspacewithlove.com/nasa-astronaut-requirements/